# Operators Precedence in C

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

```
printf ("%d \n", 2 > !3 && 4 - 1 != 5 || 6 ) ;
```

Can someone explain to me how this is evaluated ? What I am most confused about is the `!` symbol in front of the 3... how to evaluate `2 > !3` ?

Comment: See the operator precedence table for C and find out the answer by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

! is the logical not. Meaning it returns 1 for 0 or 0 for any other value.

```
!0 == 1

!1 == 0

!897489 == 0
```

So in your example `2 > !3` will be evaluted `2 > 0` which is `1`

For your whole expression you will have

```
2 > !3 && 4 - 1 != 5 || 6 
2 > 0  && 3 != 5 || 6
1 && 1 || 6                    && is higher precedence || but some compiler will warn (gcc)
1 || 6                         the 6 will not be evaluated (touched) because of short-circuit evaluation
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a table of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence).  From this we can deduce that **in your expression**

- `!` has the highest precedence
- `-` comes next
- `>` comes next
- `!=` comes next
- `&&` comes next
- `||` comes next

`!` means logical not `!0 == 1`, `!anythingElse == 0`.

The expression is evaluated as

```
((2 > (!3)) && ((4 - 1) != 5)) || 6
```

Generally, the order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified, so in the case of

```
2 > !3
```

the compiler is free to evaluate `!3` before evaluating`2`

However, for && and ||, the left side is always evaluated first so that short circuiting can be used (with `&&` if the left side is false (0), the right side is not evaluated, with `||` if the left side is true (anything but 0), the right side is not evaluated).  In the above, the `6` would never be evaluated because the left side of `||` is true.  With

```
6 || ((2 > (!3)) && ((4 - 1) != 5))
```

6 is true so the right side will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use parentheses to have your own order. Otherwise, operator precedence is explained in the [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

From the above link:

> 1. !3
> 2. 2 > !3

Answer (score 0):

the ! sign convert the value in 0 in binary so 2>!3 means 2>0 and this will be always true and 4-1 equals to 3 not equals to 5||6. 5||6 gives you 1 always so the whole command print 1

Comment: I'm sure the `!=` is evaluated before the `||`.